# How to use LINQ on a DataTable in Uipath

Tags: linq, uipath, uipath-activity

I am trying to filter a datatable using LINQ Query on Uipath and save the output as datatable format.
Where col A has name and Col B has Price. I am trying to filter where price is greater than a value ( price>500) and save both Name and Price of filtered result to a datatable.

Please find the image which I am trying to do.[LINQ Query from OutDT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Rx2.png)

Comment: Please post code as text. Images can't be used for copying into answers and they won't appear in search engine results. That said, also make sure there's enough information in your question to make it answerable. And... what's the actual question?

Comment: See: [How to Filter Data Tables in UiPath Studio](https://www.uipath.com/community/rpa-community-blog/four-ways-to-filter-data-table-in-uipath-studio)

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you but when in doubt on how to do anything in UiPath using code, just remember it's accepts regular VB.NET. This should make searching a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d1.asEnumerable.where(Function(x1) CInt(x1("salary"))>500).copyToDatatable

or

d1.asEnumerable.where(Function(x1) x1("salary")>500).copyToDatatable
if the salary column is already an integer

You may need to add Assembly reference as System.Data.DataSetExtensions   if drop down does not appear after you type d1.asEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Filter with LINQ:

```
(From row In YourDataTable.AsEnumerable Where CInt(row("price").ToString) > 500 Select row).CopyToDataTable
```

If you found error message:

```
AsEnumerable is not a member of 'System.Data.Datatable'
```

Please add reference below to your xaml file.

```
<AssemblyReference>System.Data.DataSetExtensions</AssemblyReference>
```

Reference: https://forum.uipath.com/t/asenumerable-is-not-a-member-of-system-data-datatable/69198/2?u=akkapolk

Answer (score 0):

You can also work in a function method approach to LINQ rather than a SQL-like syntax.

```
DT_Data = DT_Data.AsEnumerable.Where(
  Function(x) CINT(x("Price")) > 500
).CopyToDataTable
```

You can treat data in the DataTable with `.Select(Func)`
Returning you a collection of however you treat the data.